# dygraph on mouse over date format

Tags: date, format, dygraphs

Is it possible to change the format on the onMouseOver event in Dygraph?
Currently the format is:
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS

I would like it to display as

MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Is it possible to change the current format?
Thanks for your assistance.
Jay

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the `valueFormatter` option on the x-axis: http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueFormatter

For example,

```js
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  axes: {
    x: {
      valueFormatter: function(ms) {
        return new Date(ms).strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/772/

It's worth noting that Date.strftime() is not a standard JavaScript method: it's provided by strftime.js, which is included in the standard dygraphs bundle.