# Dygraphs format date issue

Tags: javascript, date, dygraphs

I'm trying to format date in Dygraphs on mouseover from Y-m-d  to  d-m-Y.

I've seen some pages about this question and it seems that the right answer is to put under the Dygraphs options:

```
     axes: {
            x: {

                   valueFormatter: function(ms) {
                   new Date(ms).strftime('d-m-Y');
                   }
                }
           }
```

but for me it doesn't work, it removes totaly the date and the other data on mouse over.

I've tried for hours but I can't fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Where does the *strftime* method of Date instances come from? Is that supplied by *dygraphs* or some other library?

Comment: It should be supplied by dygraphs, I found it in this page

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846944/dygraph-on-mouse-over-date-format?rq=1) .

I eventually came to the solution in this other page

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148482/how-to-format-date-and-time-in-dygraphs-legend-according-to-user-locale/32174139)

    axes: {
        x: {
            valueFormatter: function (ms) {
                return new Date(ms).toLocaleDateString();
            }

Thanks

Comment: If *toLocaleDateString* does the job, good. But note that the output is implementation dependent and even where options are supported, you can't precisely specify the format such as leading zeros, 12/24 time, placement of commas and whitespace, etc.